# Embed a html found on web in RMarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I found this `.html` on the web:

http://shabal.in/visuals/kmeans/1.html

How would I embed this link to my Rmd? Here is my YAML:

```
---
title: "Try R Workshop: Clustering"
author: "Jason Baik"
date: "02/19/2019"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
runtime: shiny
---
```

I've tried

`<iframe src='http://shabal.in/visuals/kmeans/3.html' ></iframe>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<iframe>` works. You just have to open the knitted html in a browser to render it:

[image]

Note that you can style the `<iframe>` using `<style>` tag or change the size of the frame using built-in options. To be safe, it might also be a good idea to add a message for browsers that doesn't support iframes:

```
<iframe width='1000px' height='1000px' src='http://shabal.in/visuals/kmeans/3.html' >
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes</p>
</iframe>
```